# Parse - Add an object to a pointer

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to add an object to a pointer column. But I get this error.

```
I2014-11-19T19:21:47.066Z] Failed while unmark/marking{"code":111,"message":"can't add a relation to an non-relation field"}
```

This makes total sense because I am trying to access the pointer column using `user.relation("favoritedDealsPointer")`.

Could someone please guide me how I can add an object to a pointer

```
if (deal) {
                var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
                userQuery.equalTo("objectId", userObjectId);
                userQuery.include("favoritedDealsPointer");
                userQuery.first({
                    success: function(user) {
                        console.log("Found User. stringify now:" + JSON.stringify(user));
                        if (user) {
                            Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
                            var dealRelation = user.relation("favoritedDealsPointer");
                            if (shouldMark == "mark") {
                                dealRelation.add(deal);
                            } else if (shouldMark == "unmark") {
                                dealRelation.remove(deal);
                            }
                            user.save().then(function(user) {
                                response.success(deal);
                            }, function(error) {
                                console.log("Failed while unmark/marking" + JSON.stringify(error));
                                response.error(deal, error);
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log("No such user exists");
                            response.error(deal, "Not found");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log("Error in the outer" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        response.error(deal, "Not found");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("No such deal exists");
                response.error(deal, "Deal Not found");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it's the `favouritedDealsPointer` column on the `user` object, and you want to add a pointer to your `deal` object, you can use something like this:

```
user.set("favouritedDealsPointer", deal);
```

However, a `Pointer` in Parse only supports a 1:1 relationship, and if you've called your column `favouritedDealsPointer` (plural on deals) then I suspect that you're wanting to store a relationship to more than one object, in which case a `Relation` may be a more appropriate column type.

Comment: awesome... this works.. thank you
and you were right about the column being a relation. i changed it to a pointer now... 
relating to this, can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027419/parse-using-relation-v-s-pointer