# Parse - Using Relation v/s pointer

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a user table which has two relations favoritedDeals and redeemedDeals.

To show deals to user which are neither favorited or redeemed. Since these are relations, I have to make a query to get all the favoritedDeals then redeemedDeals, pick all the objectIds (by running a for loop on both the results) and run a query against the Deal table by using

```
allDealsQuery.notContainedIn("objectId", userDeals);
```

All of this works for me. But then I want to avoid making two separate query calls to get the favoritedDeals and redeemedDeals. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I don't believe there is a simpler way. I wish there was. If you had the reverse relation (e.g., your Deal had favouritedBy<Users> and redeemedBy<Users> columns), you might be able to do it with a single query as you should be able to filter on the Deal query by not including results where the user is in the favouritedBy or redeemedBy. But that would probably require a big rewrite.

Comment: @rickerbh you should post that comment as an answer.